# Chromatic Aberrations in HDR images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, hdr

Does anybody know how to fix this chromatic aberrations (magenta coloured lines around the leafs) in Photoshop CS 5? The image is a tone mapped HDR image generated from 3 images. Lens correction was done before the HDR image was generated.

[image: HDR Image with chromatic aberrations.]

Answer (score 1):

What you see is not chromatic aberrations.
It´s just the movement of the leafs between shots.

In your's HDR software you must check the option «reduce ghosts» or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Note:  I found this via this question on photo.stackexchange which seems to have quite an amount of stuff on [chromatic aberrations](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chromatic-aberration), more than I was expecting to be honest as I didn't think it would be that common an effect.

It seem there is a part of the Adobe suite called "Photoshop Lightroom" which can apparently be used to adjust out these aberrations, see this tutorial on [how to reduce chromatic aberration](http://www.dpnotes.com/how-to-reduce-chromatic-aberration-using-adobe-photoshop-lightroom/) found via [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/photographic-techniques-to-avoid-chromatic-aberration).

Comment: I have already reduced chromatic aberrations for the 3 single images. But it cannot be removed completely. The HDR toning seems to emphasis chromatic aberrations. For the moment, I remove the aberrations by using the Stamp Tool or one of the Healing Tools, but this is very uncomfortable. By the way, I used Lightroom to reduce chromatic aberrations, but Photoshop can to it too.

Comment: Lightroom is just branded Photoshop Lightroom. It has little to do with PS.

Comment: Yes, I know this.